# Simple Wordpress form submit throws 404 when inputting numeric in input field

Tags: wordpress, forms, http-post

I noticed a strange bug when testing out one of our Wordpress apps.

I have a form with an input field and if I type a number such as "3" anywhere in the input text Wordpress will throw a 404:

```
<input name="author" type="text" />
```

If I change the name attribute from author to anything else, it works fine:

```
<input name="bob" type="text" />
```

I'm not a Wordpress guru or even a PHP dev so I apologize if this is trivial. I've stripped out everything possible from this PHP page. Is there some Wordpress magic going on here where "author" is some sort of reserved word? Here's the entire PHP file (the header is a simple nav-bar and the footer just calls wp_footer()....):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: MyTemplate
 */

get_header();

    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])):
        echo "<H4>Submitted!</H4>";
    else:
?>

    <form id="my-form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
        <input name="author" type="text" /><br/><br/>

        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

<?php
    endif;
get_footer();
```

Comment: I should add that this is pretty much a base install of Wordpress using Vagrant (https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) and the only third party plugin is "Advanced Custom Fields". I disabled the custom fields plugin and it had no effect. This is bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

OK wow.. So it looks like there are reserved words in form posts:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Sorry for such a novice question.